# Code to transfer images using Bump API

Tags: android

Hii,

We have downloaded Bump chat demo application. Application is working bt connectivity is very slow and after some time connectiion gets lost.. I have also tried to transfer images using the same Bump API. bt it is not workin

Comment: Hi surbhi, post the code here, then i will give you solution.

Comment: @surabhi hiii i want imaplement same like you.can you plz provide some code or demo for sending images between two android device using bump.i hope have you completed the project.